# Is there a way to clear the "Running head:" next to BREAST CANCER RESEARCH in my short title on the first page?

Tags: latex

I dowloaded the APA 6th manuscript latex format for my research but the first-page shortitle has a "Running head:" before the short title of my research. How do I delete this so the short title is simply BREAST CANCER RESEARCH? It runs fine in the subsequent pages though. The template uses the \shorttitle in command in latex for the short title. I dounloaded the manuscript from https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/your-apa6-style-manuscript/kngbbqpypjcq.
I am running the following codes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{bm}


\title{Breast Cancer Research}
\shorttitle{Breast Cancer Research}
\author{John Doe}
\affiliation{XYZ University}

\abstract{Your abstract here.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your question self-sustained, e.g. add a small but compilable [mre] so that it is understandable without following external links.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{bm}


\title{Breast Cancer Research}
\shorttitle{Breast Cancer Research}
\author{John Doe}
\affiliation{XYZ University}

\abstract{Your abstract here.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the `titlepage` pagestyle like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{bm}


\title{Breast Cancer Research}
\shorttitle{Breast Cancer Research}
\author{John Doe}
\affiliation{XYZ University}

\abstract{Your abstract here.}

\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{%
    \lhead{\MakeUppercase{\@shorttitle}}%
    \rhead{\thepage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Please also note that you should not use the `utf8x` option with current latex. Use `utf8` or simply nothing instead.